# How to show custom UICollectionViewCell by NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, nsarray, uicollectionviewcell

I have three custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

- RepoOfTheMonthCell
- FromTheEditorsCell
- WorldPremiereCell

and I have a `NSArray` contains order of these cells and contents which these cells should show. ('cellClass' is a class.)

```
(
    "<RSHomeItem> \n   [title]: REPO\n   OF THE\n   MONTH\n   [img]: https://nexusrepo.kro.kr/repostore/img0.png\n   [url]: https://nexusrepo.kro.kr/\n   [cellClass]: RepoOfTheMonth\n   [subtitle]: <nil>\n</RSHomeItem>",
    "<RSHomeItem> \n   [title]: REPO STORE\n   [img]: https://nexusrepo.kro.kr/repostore/img1.png\n   [url]: <nil>\n   [cellClass]: FromTheEditors\n   [subtitle]: Welcome to the\n   Repo Store!\n</RSHomeItem>",
    "<RSHomeItem> \n   [title]: FEATURED REPO\n   [img]: https://nexusrepo.kro.kr/repostore/img2.png\n   [url]: https://nexusrepo.kro.kr\n   [cellClass]: WorldPremiere\n   [subtitle]: <nil>\n</RSHomeItem>"
)
```

So, In `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`
I looped the `NSArray` like this.

`self.listHome` is a `NSArray`. and this array is special so I need to use `RSHomeItem(JSONModel)` to get value of 'cellClass' in string.

```c
for (RSHomeItem *item in self.listHome) {
    NSLog(@"class: %@", item.cellClass);
}
```

this method logged

```
class: RepoOfTheMonth
class: FromTheEditors
class: WorldPremiere
```

So I wrote this

```c
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int i = 0;
    for (RSHomeItem *item in self.listHome) {
        NSIndexPath *iIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        if ([item.cellClass isEqualToString:@"RepoOfTheMonth"]) {
            RepoOfTheMonthCell *repo = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RepoOfTheMonth" forIndexPath:iIndexPath];
            [repo.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.img]];
            [repo withTitle:item.title URL:item.url];

            return repo;
        } else if ([item.cellClass isEqualToString:@"FromTheEditors"]) {
            FromTheEditorsCell *editors = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FromTheEditors" forIndexPath:iIndexPath];
            [editors.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.img]];
            editors.titleLabel.text = item.title;
            editors.subtitleLabel.text = item.subtitle;

            return editors;
        } else if ([item.cellClass isEqualToString:@"WorldPremiere"]) {
            WorldPremiereCell *premiere = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"WorldPremiere" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            [premiere.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.img]];
            [premiere withTitle:item.title URL:item.url];

            return premiere;
        }

        i = i + 1;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

It builds well but It shows three `RepoOfTheMonthCell` with the same data instead of showing cells in this order.

1. RepoOfTheMonthCell
2. FromTheEditorsCell
3. WorldPremiereCell

numberOfSection is “1” and numberOfRow is “self.listHome.count”

Comment: attach your number of section `func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int ` in your question

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh numberOfSection is “1” and row is “self.listHome.count”

Comment: make a break point and see the value in `item.cellClass` for each iteration.

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh I think It's because of `return cell;` this makes ignore the loop.

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh just found a way to fix it. It's in the answer. check it out.

Comment: great @peter, yes ! you should not have used the loop inside it !
Do you know why you should not use the loop ?

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh yeah, return makes re-run its method so return shouldn't be in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't need to loop it.

```c
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RSHomeItem *item = self.listHome[indexPath.row];

    if ([item.cellClass isEqualToString:@"RepoOfTheMonth"]) {
        RepoOfTheMonthCell *repo = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RepoOfTheMonth" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [repo.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.img]];
        [repo withTitle:item.title URL:item.url];

        return repo;
    }

    if ([item.cellClass isEqualToString:@"FromTheEditors"]) {
        FromTheEditorsCell *editors = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FromTheEditors" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [editors.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.img]];
        editors.titleLabel.text = item.title;
        editors.subtitleLabel.text = item.subtitle;

        return editors;
    }

    if ([item.cellClass isEqualToString:@"WorldPremiere"]) {
        WorldPremiereCell *premiere = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"WorldPremiere" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [premiere.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.img]];
        [premiere withTitle:item.title URL:item.url];

        return premiere;
    }

    return nil;
}
```